# Using COM object in VB

Tags: vb.net, com

Trying to find how to tell VB to use COM object. In C# it is quite simple - select `Add Reference - > COM -> select library you need` and add simple code like this:

```
        AMyClass c = new AMyClass();
        int i;
        c.A_Myfnc(out i);
```

It works fine in `C#`.

How to make the same in VB?

I stuck in when I was trying to add COM object reference in VB 2012. Where is exact place where I can add my OCX reference? I was trying to ad component to toolbox, but in could not find my component in COM tab list. My COM is not visual.

Then I tried to use VB 2013. There I found that I can add reference in solution explorer like in C# and I see my component registered. That is fine, but what is syntax of creating COM object in VB?

Comment: Just do the same thing...add a reference to it.  Can you elaborate on what isn't working for you?

Comment: I have added problem description in question body

Comment: If your "COM is not visual" then there is no point in trying to add it to the toolbox.  You need to use Project > Add Reference instead.  Works exactly the same way as it does in C#, the dialog is not different.

Comment: Thank you, now problem by adding COM reference to VB 2012 is solved. But how to create COM object in VB code?